# reconstructing ext4 inode structure after folder deletion

Tags: partition, ext4, data-recovery, inode, journaling

My `ext4` partition that had my whatsapp data had its entire folder deleted ( that is file / folder delete - no `partition` ).
As I understand  `inodes`  have the `metadata tree` for files  including their names location etc. The problem I face is the raw files ( without original filenames and paths ) can be recovered b*ut original original file names with paths are missing* . It was the app that deleted folder. This folder was `mounted` to `ext4` partition on android phone. Partition image is already copied & to backup

**What I did**

& I tried following `Testdisk` -- No valid `partition Extundelete` and `ext4Magic` : No luck . `Inode` data came out empty and `foremost` got some data but `metadata` missing ( explained further down ) 3rd Party tools : *Easus data recovery / Hetmann / r-studio* : Please see screenshot . The folder and files I am looking for are 0 byte Running entire deep scan takes some 8 hrs and I get RAW files without original file names ( e.g. filexxx.jpg ) and that is of NO USE . I need file names with metadata e,g. original filenames and their paths i.e. somehow the raw files recovered should be mapped to the 0 byte file names or any other way the original file names can be recovered
See the attached picture.

Is there any utility that can reconstruct the deleted `inodes` ?  or any methodology[image] approach to do it.